# php to shell script to php for a value via passwordless ipv6 ssh tunnel

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, ipv6

the topology is server1 -> IPv6 ssh tunnel -> server2 (secret sauce = $ip_addr)
the code logic follows the same path  php cgi script -> shell script -> retrieves the secret sauce $ip_addr and echo's it out.
I am trying to retrieve the $ip_addr value from server2 and display it on the initiating server1.

******  code on webserver that wants the value $ip_addr which is echoed from mailserver *****

```
<?php

$addr['ip_addr'] = shell_exec('sudo /home/wemail1/cgi-bin/ip_addr_stats');
$ip = $_POST['ip_addr'];
#echo "<pre>$ip['ip_addr']</pre>";
echo $ip['ip_addr'];
var_dump($_POST);


?>
```

******* *shell script that is executed from above to call on php script on mailserver* *

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -p 22 -6 2600:3c01:e000:44::14 "php /var/www/localhost/cgi-bin/postUser2master.php  .ssh;"
```

*************  script on mailserver that retrieves $ip_addr  **********

```
<?php
#require_once('auth.php');
$master = fopen('/etc/postfix/master.cf', 'a+');
$id = 'bob';
$ip_addr = '2600:3c01:e000:44:0:0:0:10';
$valid = false;
while (($buffer = file_get_contents('/etc/postfix/master.cf')) !== false) {
    if (strpos($buffer,$id) !== false) {
        $valid = TRUE;
        echo $ip_addr;
        break;
    }else{
        fwrite($master,
            "\r\n".$id." unix -       -       n       -       -       smtp \n
-o syslog_name=postfix-".$id."\n
-o smtp_bind_address6=".$ip_addr."\n"
            );

    }
echo $ip_addr;
}
fclose($master);

?>
```

********************* error  from first script ***************************

```
var_dump($_POST); -->  Arrayarray(0) { }

Undefined index: ip_addr
```

*****************  NOTE: ******************************
I have another script that recovers statistics via the same path and basically the same code that works perfectly. The only difference is, instead of calling on pslogsumm, I am calling on another php script. So there are no network errors to contend with or anything weird. It is as though they are on a LAN.

******************  *update*  *********************
This command works perfect on the command line:

```
emailer1 cgi-bin # /usr/bin/ssh -p 22 -6 2600:3c01:e000:44::14 '/usr/bin/php /var/www/localhost/cgi-bin/postUser2master.php .ssh'
2600:3c01:e000:44:0:0:0:10emailer1 cgi-bin #

As does this one:

dev-box-201 www # /home/wemail1/cgi-bin/ip_addr_stats
+ ssh -p 22 -6 2600:3c01:e000:44::14 'php /var/www/localhost/cgi-bin/postUser2master.php  .ssh'
2600:3c01:e000:44:0:0:0:10dev-box-201 www #
```

It spits out the ip address perfectly. That is the value I need but cannot get to.

Comment: how are you calling the script that prints the "error" (which most probably is actually a notice)?

Comment: Could do do the following? Modify the shell script to the following: http://pastebin.com/Jcp05WiC ? By running the bash script in debug mode we'll be able to see exactly what's happening on each level. Also, that script doesn't specify a user ... who are you logging in as? Does that user have permissions to get the /etc/postfix/master.cf file etc ( usually owned by root no? ). Also are you using ssh keys to get from one server to the next w/o passwords?

Comment: @Gerald Schneider "Notice: Undefined index: ip_addr in /home/wemail1/www/index.php on line 147" is the exact error. I am calling/initiating via shell_exec() in the first script. That call travels down the tunnel and is supposed to hit the cgi on the of the email server via port 22. (permissions are the same as the working script mentioned). Since it's a shell scripts call, the output of echo $ip_addr should just pop up in the buffer like my other perl script. It didn't, then I tried POST, that didn't work either.

Comment: @Malcolm Jones no output to logs. I even created a static path to etc...  'chown wemail1:www-pub /var/log/postuser2master.log' and logs are empty. tried all the silly things like restart apache also jic.

Comment: @brad 2 things. 1. is ip_addr_stats chmod'd to an executable? 2. What happens if you replace the shell_exec with the direct command you're running? eg shell_exec('sudo /usr/bin/ssh -p 22 -6 2600:3c01:e000:44::14 "php /var/www/localhost/cgi-bin/postUser2master.php  .ssh;"'); Could you let us know what happens when you do that?

Comment: @brad also, could you use full paths for all of the things you're running? eg instead of just php, /usr/bin/php ( some users might not be fully aware of the complete path for some of these linux commands ? )

Comment: @Gerald Schneider all scripts are chmod +x.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I tried a few different methods, "$addr = shell_exec('sudo /usr/bin/ssh -p 22 -6." 2600:3c01:e000:44::14"./usr/bin/php" /var/www/localhost/cgi-bin/postUser2master.php "./usr/bin/ssh | /usr/bin/tee -a." /var/log/postuser2master.log 2>&1"');"  produces a NULL values with var_dump($addr);

Comment: @Malcolm Jone http://www.bpaste.net/show/rB777uRrcBwjfzBauz1E/

Comment: BTW, it's considered good form to accept answers which helped you solve your problems. You don't seem to have _ever_ done this. This may discourage some people from helping you.

Comment: @brad interesting. Okay some more follow up questions, I have an ideas what might be happening. 1. in your ssh command, you never specify the user, shouldnt you pass a -u wemail1 in there? 2. Do you have full access to the second server ( root ) ? If so, verify if wemail1 is part of the sudoers group ( also if know better, running a sudo command remotely requires a ttl ... so try passing ssh -t -t ( yes two of them ). 3. Try to reproduce everything the same way php is calling it, a. ssh to server1 b. change to user who's running the script ( apache? ) to do that run su USER. c. try running,

Comment: @brad your command directly. ssh -p 22 -6 2600:3c01:e000:44::14 "php /var/www/localhost/cgi-bin/postUser2master.php  .ssh;" .. what happens when do you do that? does it connect correctly? does it return anything? If you really need to debug more pass -vvv to ssh so you get a really verbose output. This will really give us the hint we need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be very confused with your variable names and your code flow.

Let us look closely at your code.

```
$addr['ip_addr'] = shell_exec('sudo /home/wemail1/cgi-bin/ip_addr_stats');
```

Here you assign the output of this shell command to the variable `$addr['ip_addr']`. So far so good.

```
$ip = $_POST['ip_addr'];
```

Here you assign a POST variable to the variable `$ip`. I don't know why you are doing this; there was no context provided for it and no apparent reason to do it.

```
echo $ip['ip_addr'];
```

Finally you attempt to echo the value of the array member `$ip['ip_addr']` which of course you supposedly got from the POST variable earlier. Of course, that value wasn't an array to begin with (and probably didn't even exist) so you get the message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: ip_addr in /home/wemail1/www/index.php on line 147
```

Finally:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Which of course returns an empty `Array`. As I suspected, you hadn't done a POST request to begin with.

---

So, you say you want the output from the shell command. You assigned it to `$addr['ip_addr']`. Why not just use that and remove all this extraneous clutter?

Comment: $addr['ip_addr'] = shell_exec('sudo /home/wemail1/cgi-bin/ip_addr_stats');  ->  var_dump($addr);  =   NULL
. This is the code I first tried and failed. $ip = $_POST['ip_addr']; was debugging, trying to figure out why.

Comment: If you were debugging that script, you added your debugging code to the wrong script!

Comment: ssh -p 22 -6 2600:3c01:e000:44::14 'bash -s'."php /var/www/localhost/cgi-bin/postUser2master.php"   the error is in my shell script. that command just hangs. but running "php /var/www/localhost/cgi-bin/postUser2master.php" on the remote/target machine works like a champ. I have tried many different versions.

Comment: You should probably update your question, strip out any extraneous stuff, and focus it clearly on the part which you're sure isn't working. You probably should also explain the overall objective here, as there is almost certainly a better way to do whatever it is. Also remember that information should be in your post, rather than in comments, as many people do not see comments.

Comment: Just updated though the issue is the same from the beginning, unable to display the value returned from the script. oddly, my first script that was working, now is NULL too  http://bpaste.net/show/128164/

Comment: Also I added a passwordless key for my webroot user also. no errors in any logs, messages or apache, both servers. I tried with and without sudo. still NULL.

Answer (score 0):

it has actually turned out to be a hostkey issue.
Still sorting it out.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this (using [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/))?:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('tcp://[2600:3c01:e000:44]:14', 22);
$ssh->login();

echo $ssh->exec('php /var/www/localhost/cgi-bin/postUser2master.php  .ssh');
```

Calling login without any parameters should do passwordless auth.

One advantage of phpseclib, imho, is that if it doesn't work you can get logs that'll assist in diagnostics. So if not even phpseclib works posting the logs here should help.